# Why Bundle Install is installing gems in vendor/bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

Whenever I do `bundle install` all of the gems get installed at

```
app_dir/vendor/bundle
```

path and consumes loads of disk space. I also tried installing gems where it should get installed i.e gemsets while development by this:

```
bundle install --no-deployement
```

but this isn't working for me and installeing gems at `vendor/bundle`. How can I make it to be installed globally for all applications or in ruby gemsets location ? I also tried removing `.bundle/config` but nothing changed.

I am using:

```
rvm version: 1.23.14
ruby version: 2.0.0-p247
rails 3.2.13
```

Here is my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
alias pg='pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log'

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

My `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Some other information that you might need:

```
aman@Amandeeps-MacBook-Pro ~/Projects/qe (develop)*$ which bundle
/Users/aman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle

aman@Amandeeps-MacBook-Pro ~/Projects/qe (develop)*$ rbenv which bundle
/Users/aman/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/bundle

amandeep@Amandeeps-MacBook-Pro ~/Projects/qe (develop)*$ rbenv which ruby
/Users/aman/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

aman@Amandeeps-MacBook-Pro ~/Projects/qe (develop)*$ rbenv gemset active
rbenv: NO such command `gemset'

aman@Amandeeps-MacBook-Pro ~/Projects/qe (develop)*$ which rails
/Users/aman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rails
```

I tried this also but didn't helped:

```
bundle install --system
```

and removing `.bundle` directory.

Please help me in installing gems in gemsets not `vendor/bundle` or a default place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Use `bundle env` to view paths and bundle configuration
2. After this set bundle path to  `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247` like this:

   ```
   bundle install --path ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
   ```

   which is global and also you can use your own custom path.
3. Post this `bundle install` will never need `path` again and will always install all of your gems in that `directory(~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 in my case`) for that app not in `app_folder/vendor/bundle`

Comment: #2 has been deprecated. Now use: `bundle config set --local path ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247`

Answer (score 122):

In your project folder you will have `.bundle` directory that holds configuration for `bundler`. try deleting that folder. it should reset the install path for your gems back to system-wide settings.

In the case you just want to edit the install path, opening `.bundle/config` with your favorite editor should show you the path to `vendor/bundle`. Removing that line will restore it to defaults without removing other configs you might have.

Also, another less frequent scenario is your system-wide settings being messed up. According to @NaoiseGolden:

> I had to delete `.bundle` from my Home folder (rm -rf ~/.bundle). You can check out your configuration running `bundle env`

Comment: Likewise solved it for me, but can anyone explain how those settings got set in the first place? They're not in my source control and I sure didn't create them.

Comment: @Matt At some point you ran bundle with `--deployment` flag or `--path` flag. That resulted changing install path to `vendor` and the settings got autosaved to `.bundle`. That's the most probable scenario.

Comment: I had to delete .bundle from my Home folder (`rm -rf ~/.bundle`). You can check out your configuration running `bundle env`.

Comment: @IuriG. is absolutely right. I looked back through my bash command history and found that, for some reason or another (probably following advice on some blog post or SO question without knowing what I was doing), I had run `bundle --path=vendor/bundle`, which resulted in the creation of `.bundle/config`. This solution (`rm -rf .bundle`) was very simple and fixed everything.

Comment: @OP original post: This worked perfectly, thank you. Saved me so much time.

Answer (score 34):

Try installing using

```
bundle install --system
```

I think initially the bundle install was run with `--path` flag and bundler now rememebers that confguration.

From the bundler [man page](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html#REMEMBERED-OPTIONS)

> Some options are remembered between calls to bundle install, and by the Bundler runtime.
>
> Subsequent calls to bundle install will install gems to the directory originally passed to *--path*. The Bundler runtime will look for gems in that location. You can revert this option by running *bundle install --system*.

***EDIT***: As mentioned in comments below, and also otherwise, this installs the gems system wide. In case you are using rvm etc to manage your environment for different apps, check [@IuriG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963957/1860929) mentioned above.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Interesting. So what happens if you try specifyiing some other path - example `bundle install --path sample`? My guess is, that wouldn't work either. If that is the case, can you reinstall bundler using `gem unistall bundler` and `gem install bundler`?

Comment: I did that too. Even I have installed rvm and ruby again.

Comment: Can u give me some example what is default $BUNDLE_PATH? is it ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 ?

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Yes, it should be something similar. Have you used the `--binstubs` flag earlier?

Comment: No. I haven't used it.

Comment: I would not do this, unless you intend for your computer's Ruby to be the version to use in rails.  If you do, like I did, I did a rvm reinstall xxx to start fresh.

Comment: @TayloredWebSites you are right, have added an edit for that. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Thanks! this really helped.

Answer (score 7):

Try running `bundle env`. This will tell you where the path configuration is set.

Comment: This helped in viewing the path. Now I have changed bundle path to ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 and made it not to install at vendor/bundle

Comment: If you're trying to install to your system gem location, I recommend _not_ setting it inside bundle config at all. You can just delete the line. Bundler will default to using your `GEM_HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, acording to your info, it seems that you have installed both rvm and rbenv. Thats a [very bad idea](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation). You have to delete one of them (rbenv + bundler works like a charm for me, didnt try rvm).

In regard to your question check `.bundle/config` in your project, as all the configuration for bundle to that project lies there (if its still deleted, you can create a new one). You migh want to add this line (or change it, if its already there): `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '0'` for sharing gems, they go where your `BUNDLE_PATH:` is set (`BUNDLE_PATH: vendor` in my case).

For the global configuration file look in `~/.bundle/config`

Also this man page could be of use: [bundle config](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/bundle-config.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

To Install Gem in system wide avoiding path vendor/bundle, just run the following command in project directory

```
bundle install --system
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew install rbenv
$ rbenv install 2.7.6
$ rbenv install -l
2.7.6
$ rbenv global 2.7.6
$ gem install bundler
$ brew install rbenv-gemset
$ rbenv gemset create 2.7.6 mygemset
$ gem env home
/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/gemsets/mygemset
$ gem install rails
$ rails new myapp && cd myapp
$ bundle install
$ bundle show --paths
/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/gemsets/myapp/gems/actioncable-7.0.1
...
$ bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
$ file .bundle
$ .bundle: directory
$ cat .bundle/config
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
$ bundle install # Note from time to time you will get some bizarre error "Could not find timeout-0.2.0 in any of the sources". Simply delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle install again.
$ bundle show --paths
/Users/myuser/myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-7.0.4
$ bundle config set --local system 'true' # or you may want to   delete BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle" from .bundle/config
$ rm -rf vendor/bundle
$ rbenv gemset active
mygemset global
$ bundle install
$ bundle show --paths
/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/gemsets/mygemset
```

All in all, when you install a ruby version manager, such as the preferable rbenv, then it will install gems according to its setup. However, if you update .config/bundle in your project to use 'vendor/bundle', then that's where 'bundle install' will install gems. Sometimes this is used to keep project specific gems, instead of using a gemset tool like rbenv-gemset. Other times it is required for deployment, such as deploying to AWS Lambda on its ruby2.7 runtime. The use of 'vendor/bundle' can be easily removed by removing its reference from .config/bundle as shown above. Once it is removed, it will default to the gem environment that exists globally, which in the above case is managed by rbenv.