# Is it possible to verify if all gems in a Gemfile.lock exist at https://rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is it possible to verify if all gems in a `Gemfile.lock` file exist at https://rubygems.org?

I recently updated my elastic beanstalk platform version, and it failed due to the following error:

> Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.3), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.3) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.3) that hasn't been removed in order to install.

It was difficult to debug due to all the complexities of a managed deploy system.

The reason it failed is that the author of mimemagic has removed version 0.3.3, and so I needed to update the gem to 0.3.6. (see gem versions history here: https://rubygems.org/gems/mimemagic/versions)

So my question is: is there a command you can run, e.g. `bundle check_sources` that scans the gems and versions in your `Gemfile.lock` and hits https://rubygems.org to verify that they all exist and are still available?

It would be similar to what `bundle check` does, but instead of looking for the gems on your local machine, it would look for them at the remote source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After suggesting a feature request with the developers of `bundler` here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4487, they suggested at least a viable work-around. Simply run this command:

```
bundle install --deployment --redownload
```

The `--redownload` (or `--force`) switch will force the download of every gem, even if the required versions are already available locally.

The `--deployment` switch forces the usage of the exact versions specified in your Gemfile (and ignore patch upgrades like `~> 0.3.2` which would normally upgrade to e.g. `0.3.6`). The use of `--deployment` is common practice during deployments.

This solution isn't ideal since it requires a full reinstall of all your bundle's gems. But it works!

Thanks to https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez for this suggestion.

Comment: Note that if you run this locally, you may notice gems located in `./vendor/bundle/`. This is caused by the `--deployment` flag. To change this back, TL;DR run `rm -rf .bundle` in your project directory to revert back to default settings, and then run `rm -rf vendor/bundle/`. `bundle install` will now work as before. More detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961821/why-bundle-install-is-installing-gems-in-vendor-bundle

Answer (score -3):

i'm experienced the same exact issue today, im running my project on docker and the solution was to change the mimemagic version on the Gemfile.lock, i dont know if is an optimal solution but saved my day :)

Comment: Hi @PauloBufalinoMora.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.    The OP has asked if there's a way to verify the gems - do you have any input on that?